# Non-static method error - jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu plugin - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, accordion, non-static

I've been using the jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu plugin for quite some time now but when I updated to WordPress `4.1` the plugin throws an error message that looks like the screenshot provided [here.](http://i.xomf.com/spwcx.jpg)

I think I've located it to the `dcwp_jquery_accordion.php` since it doesn't display the error when those lines are commented out.
What is the correct way to use the add_action?

Thanks!

Best regards,
Marcus

```
function dc_jqaccordion(){
    global $registered_skins;

    if(!is_admin()){

        // Header styles
//      add_action( 'init', array('dc_jqaccordion', 'header') );

        // Shortcodes
        add_shortcode( 'dcwp-jquery-accordion', 'dcwp_dc_jqaccordion_shortcode' );
    }
//  add_action( 'wp_footer', array('dc_jqaccordion', 'footer') );

    $registered_skins = array();
```

Comment: Do you want some kind of script to render in the footer of your page for your `dcwp-jquery-accordion` shortcode ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue in my case was that the functions needed to be `public static function` instead of just `function`

The plugin works now.
Thanks @mmk

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use `add_action()` is like so:

```
add_action('the_action_you_want_to_target','your_function');
function your_function(){
    //your code goes here
}
```

if you want to enqueue scripts you can do it in using another `add_action()` like so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','My_Stylesheets_and_Scripts'); 
function My_Stylesheets_and_Scripts(){
 wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

The `true` part means the script will get enqueued in the footer. `false` renders the script in the header.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what to do.
Here's the link to it http://pastebin.com/iw4rC21d
@mmk